# Replace a html tag with another without removing the class

Tags: jquery, html

I have a button like this one:

```
<button class="simplefavorite-button" data-postid="616" data-siteid="1" data-groupid="1" data-favoritecount="0"><i class="fa fa-heart ico_heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

I have tried this code to change `<button>` tag with `<li>` tag:

```
jQuery('button').contents().unwrap().wrap('<li/>');
```

But its removing all other data and class name. Is there any other method to keep the class in the new tag?

Comment: Use an 'id' to pull out the specific button or you could use another class etc. Your jQuery('button') is returning all buttons on the page.

Comment: Use [`clone(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) if you want to keep data and events on the cloned element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes are iterable.  Just copy them manually before wrapping the contents.

```js
jQuery('button').each(function(){
  var clone = document.createElement('li');
  for(var i = 0, len = this.attributes.length; i < len; i++) {
    clone.setAttribute(this.attributes[i]['name'], this.attributes[i]['value']);
  }
  $(this).contents().unwrap().wrap(clone);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="simplefavorite-button" data-postid="616" data-siteid="1" data-groupid="1" data-favoritecount="0"><i class="fa fa-heart ico_heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

Comment: yes this is exactly what I was looking for, thankyou.

Comment: thanks but Im having a small problem with the search bar on my site I tried many different ways to use your code only in one div but cant figure it out so your code helped me so much but its changing the search button on the header too if you are around and if you can tell me what to do would be great I know its easy but for me its so difficult at the moment. thankyou again for your time.

Comment: @Gazi Went to lunch, but I'm back.  It's probably because the selector is too general. `jQuery('button')` will affect all the buttons on the site, so it's likely you just need to make it more specific.  You could try `jQuery('button.ico_heart')` instead.